# how can i test my camera on xcode without a device (using output from simulator)?

Tags: ipad, camera, ios-simulator

I am making an ipad app which uses a camera.  i do not have an ipad so i cannot test the app on a device.  is there a way to figure out if the camera works by using the output from the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you're up a creek here. If memory serves all pure going to see is a black screen in simulator. I know it's covered in the developer library but since they're overhauling the portal I can't get to the exact verbiage. It specifically mentions the simulaor can't emulate the accelerometer or camera.